# I have only 4 quick toggles on my new lumia 640 XL

Tags: lumia

I have only 4 quick toggles on my new lumia 640 XL , How can I increase it to 5 ,

I have seen in video in youtube that  lumia 640 XL has 5 toggles in the Action Center,

But now I am not having it , could any one help , Is the mobile i bought is really genuie  or what is the problem.

Comment: Share us your OS version. Also check if you see the additional toggle when you enable settings -> start + theme -> enable Show more tiles.

Comment: Hello Thanks for responding.OS Version 8.10.15148.160;Hardware revision number 2.4.0.0; screen resolution 720*1280                                      I  went to start+theme -> there I have only .. the back ground accent color and choose photo option that all

Comment: In this below site it shows  it is 5 toggles but mine i have only 4 toogles http://unleashthephones.com/2015/04/18/microsoft-lumia-640-xl-review/

Answer (score 1):

If the article facts are correct then you would need the update 2 installed
[image: update 2 installed]

Go to notifications+actions in settings and see if the mobile data is available or not.

Also there's the good news that in Windows 10 you get 4 row 4 column expandable action centre. So check that out also

Comment: Can you provide the source link too?

Comment: http://www.nokiapoweruser.com/windows-10/   and http://betanews.com/2015/04/20/one-week-later-windows-10-technical-preview-for-phones-on-my-daily-lumia-925/